# spring data jpa - UsersRepository No property name found for type Users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, repository

Hello everyone hope you are safe with all what is happening right now.
I'm struggling with spring data jpa no property found exception

the error is that spring cannot find the users when i run the application :

```
UsersRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Users!
```

here is my code:

this is my `users.java` that contains all the fiels for the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Users users){

        this.id=users.getId();
        this.userName=users.getUserName();
        this.password=users.getPassword();
        this.roles=users.getRoles();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() { return userName; }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

this is my `UsersRepository.java`

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByName(String userName);
}
```

And finally this is `MyUsersDetailsService.java`

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       Optional<Users> optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByName(userName);

        optionalUsers
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(userName+"Utilisateur Introuvable!"));
        return optionalUsers
                .map(MyUserDetails::new).get();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your repository method name to

`Optional<Users> findByUserName(String userName);`

as you do not have property called `name`.

---

Couple of suggestions:

- Keep your entity class name as `User` instead of `Users`. (The entity class represents one record in the table which is basically an `User` )
- Let the variable `userName` be `username`. (if you go with this, then the repository method name would `findByUsername`.